# Laravel insert into db using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to insert into my db using laravel db method I can insert array using this code:

```php
if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $insert[] = [
        'Number' => $value->number,
        'Full_Name' => $value->full_name,
        'Type' => $value->type,
        'Email' => $value->email,
        ];  
    }

    if(!empty($insert)){

        $insertData = DB::table('import')->insert($insert);
        if ($insertData) {
            Session::flash('success', 'Your Data has successfully imported');
        }else {                        
            Session::flash('error', 'Error inserting the data..');
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I can insert values using insert array but I want to insert this using eloquent create method is there anything like this:

```php
$insertData = Import::create($insert);
```

I want to use this method:

```php
firstOrNew
```

How can I use eloquent method where I can insert into db and if any duplication is there it should throw error.

Import Model code:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Import extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'imports';
    protected $fillable =  [
      'id',
      'Number',
      'Full_Name',
      'Type',
      'Email',
      'created_at',
      'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

I am using laravel 5.2

Comment: You can use create to insert an array of data. You can also do `$import = new Import();` so you grab the model. Then you can do `$import->fill($request->input())->save();`

Comment: $insertData = Import::create($insert); this one is not working

Comment: Have you set your `protected $fillable = []` at the top of the model? [Take a look here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) under Mass Assignment.

Comment: Yes I set protected fillable I am getting error Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column

Comment: Then the issue would be in your migration. A value is expected and you’re providing null. You can make it nullable and then it’ll work.

Comment: same code work for db:insert what is the real issue ?

Comment: @NilaySingh please share your `Import` model code.

Comment: In the code above, $insert is an array of arrays, so the DB::table() approach will work, but if you want to use Import::create you may need to call it for each insert?

Comment: @alexkb example please

Comment: If `$insert` is an array of arrays (which is a horrible name for it btw), then `array_walk($insert, function($import) {  Import::create($import); })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using alexkb comment, I am using this code:

```
array_walk($insert, function($import) { Import::create($import); })
```

And this one is working

Answer (score 0):

You can use, firstOrCreate to avoid duplications, the first paramater will be use to finde the record, and the second will be use for new record, but not for search

```
$import= Import::firstOrCreate([
    'email' => 'email@email.com'
], [
    'Full_Name' => 'Nilay Singh',
    'Type' => 'Type'
]);
```

Comment: $insertData = DB::table('import')->insert($insert); this is working but create is noot working with same array I am getting null error

Comment: mmm, what error show?? DB::table->insert dont use Model for insert... $fillable or $guarded properties dont have effect, but with Import::create() and your array of $fillable should works..